# REMOTE ACCESS FROM ONE PLACE TO ANOTHER MS SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, remote-access

I have try to remote access from one computer to another within LAN connection. However, thru these days research a lot of the article said I need to do port forwarding. But I think in my country ISP has block this setting, I can even find the option in my router webpage.
Is there any other way to remotely access the ms sql server thru internet?

Comment: Hire someone before you get hacked (or worse). You do not have the expertise to safely expose a machine in your local network to the world via the internet. Perhaps you can use a VPN - but the term "remote access" is vague so this may not be a viable path.

Answer (score 0):

This is networking protocol. But you can do it using `Remote Desktop Connection` locally as long as you have an access to that `particular Server`.

Check the `Firewall` also to your server.

Another option is, you can access it remotely using `TEAM VIEWER`